# How do you edit XML file with Ansible module community.general.xml

Tags: xml, ansible, namespaces

Using the Ansible module `community.general.xml`, I am attempting to add a child node to the following XML data: (saved into *namespace-test.xml*)

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
  </core>
</configuration>
```

The data I would like to add, under the `core` node, is:

```xml
<xi:include href="/conf/xmlconfig-to-include.xml"/>
```

The Ansible task I am running is:

```yaml
- name: include modular XML configuration file
  community.general.xml:
    path: namespace-test.xml
    xpath: /conf:configuration/core:core
    input_type: xml
    add_children:
      - '<xi:include href="/conf/xmlconfig-to-include.xml"/>'
    namespaces:
      conf: urn:activemq
      core: urn:activemq:core
      xi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    pretty_print: yes
```

I am expecting to get this result:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <xi:include href="/conf/xmlconfig-to-include.xml"/>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

But I am getting the following error message, instead:

> Error while parsing child element: Namespace prefix xi on include is not defined

---

More information after the very usefull options suggested by β.εηοιτ.βε.

The idempotent option did not meet the additionnal requirements (non-specified initially) that I need more than one include in the XML block.

This is really what I was aiming for:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <xi:include href="/conf/addresses.xml"/>
    <xi:include href="/conf/address-settings.xml"/>
    <xi:include href="/conf/security-settings.xml"/>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really two approaches for your issue at hand:

1. **the highly recommended one**: constructing the `xpath` with the node you are expecting — `/conf:configuration/core:core/xi:include` — and just adding the required attribute.
2. in the line with your actual trial, using an `add_children`, but in a YAML form, because the XML form does not seems to cope well with namespace *<sup>[reference](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/55349)</sup>*.

Why is the first one highly recommended? Because it makes your task [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency), so, re-running your playbook won't keep on adding the same node over and over again, if it exists with the right attribute already.

So, here is the idempotent task:

```yaml
- name: include modular XML configuration file
  community.general.xml:
    path: namespace-test.xml
    xpath: /conf:configuration/core:core/xi:include
    attribute: href
    value: /conf/xmlconfig-to-include.xml
    namespaces:
      conf: urn:activemq
      core: urn:activemq:core
      xi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    pretty_print: yes
```

Which would give your expected XML.

---

And regarding the fact that you do need multiple include, the trick, then is to further specialize your xpath expression, for example:

```xml
/conf:configuration
  /core:core
    /xi:include[@href='/conf/xmlconfig-to-include.xml']
```

So, your task to add the three include nodes could end up in a loop:

```yaml
- name: include modular XML configuration file
  community.general.xml:
    path: namespace-test.xml
    xpath: /conf:configuration/core:core/xi:include[@href='{{ item }}']
    namespaces:
      conf: urn:activemq
      core: urn:activemq:core
      xi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    pretty_print: yes
  loop:
    - /conf/addresses.xml
    - /conf/address-settings.xml
    - /conf/security-settings.xml
```

---

*And if you really want the non-idempotent option, here it is:*

```yaml
- name: include modular XML configuration file
  community.general.xml:
    path: namespace-test.xml
    xpath: /conf:configuration/core:core
    add_children:
      - "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude}include":
          href: /conf/xmlconfig-to-include.xml
    namespaces:
      conf: urn:activemq
      core: urn:activemq:core
      xi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    pretty_print: yes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Both options work very well. But I have chosen for now to use the non-idempotent option because the results it produces is more close to what I was looking for. 
I have added to the orginal post a portion of the structure of the XML file I was aiming to generate.

Comment: @GullahGeechee that's still possible in an idempotent way, see the update above.

Comment: Perfect solution ! This is an xpath masterclass and I have chosen to use your last suggestion. Idempotence is the way to go definetly. Thank you very much for your time !!